# Grails examples and sample code snippets

Tags: grails, groovy

Hi I am new to Grails and I want it to study myself... so please suggest me good websites and blogs which has groovy examples and sample code snippets and cookbook examples
I have found some.

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/groovy-goodness-getting-all_25.html 
http://www.groovyexamples.org

Comment: It's not called "Groovy on Grails", it's called Grails.

Answer (score 2):

The official Grails [reference document](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) is excellent. There are also a number of [good](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599950) available